# ORA-00942 on INSERT to a newly created table

Tags: oracle, flyway

I'm doing an evaluation of FLYWAY and running a very simple script that creates a new table and insert a row to that table.  The table creates successfully but I get an ORA-942 error on the INSERT.  I have tried every permutation I can think of using upper/lower case and quoted and unquoted schema and table names.  I have also tried separating out the INSERT statement into different script from the CREATE statement - all to no avail.  Can anyone help explain the format flyway needs for the INSERT statements?

Here are the statements from my most recent attempt.  I  have tried the same statements with quotes around the table_name, with all lower case, with no quotes around the schema - nothing works.  Logged directly into the database as SYS, I can describe the table with this command:
desc "FLYWAY_USER".department

```
CREATE TABLE "FLYWAY_USER".DEPARTMENT
   ( DEPARTMENT_id      NUMBER(3)         NOT NULL,
     DEPARTMENT         VARCHAR2(64)      NOT NULL,
     display_name       VARCHAR2(64)      NOT NULL,
     description        VARCHAR2(400),
     create_date        DATE              NOT NULL,
     update_date        DATE              NOT NULL,
     created_by         VARCHAR2(80)      NOT NULL,
     updated_by         VARCHAR2(80)      NOT NULL )
TABLESPACE users;

INSERT INTO "FLYWAY_USER".DEPARTMENT
    ( DEPARTMENT_id,
      DEPARTMENT,
      display_name,
      description,
      create_date,
      update_date,
      created_by,
     updated_by )
VALUES
    ( ( SELECT Nvl( Max(DEPARTMENT_id), 0) + 1  FROM  DEPARTMENT ),
         'HUMAN_RESOURCES',
         'Human Resources',
         'The best place to eat smores or get a raise.',
         Sysdate, 
         Sysdate,
        'AT09001',
        'AT09001' );
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you post the error itself in your question...

Comment: Please edit your post to include the exact quote of your full error code as it often contains more useful information besides the name of the error.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting above - this is my first post....Here's the error:

Comment: Migration V1_5__Install_Test_Case_1.sql failed   
----------------------------------------------   
SQL State  : 42000   
Error Code : 942   
Message    : ORA-00942: table or view does not exist   
Location   : /home/weblogic/flyway/flyway-3.2/flyway-3.2.1/sql/V1_5__Install_Test_Case_1.sql    (/home/weblogic/flyway/flyway-3.2/flyway-3.2.1/sql/V1_5__Install_Test_Case_1.sql)   
Line       : 42   
Statement  : INSERT INTO "FLYWAY_USER".DEPARTMENT   
     <CUT HERE AS LINE EXCEEDS MAX>

Comment: @MaryEllen kindly update the question with the error details

Comment: Don't log into the SYS schema and expect things like this to work; SYS is special. You should, instead, create a new schema with the appropriate privileges, and ensure that your table has insert grants to the relevant schema. Alternatively, run the script as the FLYWAY_USER, ensuring they have the CREATE TABLE privilege.

Comment: I'm not logging into SYS through flyway - that is a separate database connection just to show the object exists.    Thanks for all for quick comments....the issue was the reference to DEPARTMENT in the sub-select.  If I fully qualify that the script succeeds.

Comment: As an aside, assigning ids to a pk or unique column by doing max(id) + 1 is, in general, a bad idea. It doesn't scale, and you'll end up with errors when multiple users try to add a row to the table at the same time. Instead, you should create a sequence and then use seq_name.nextval to populate the values in that column.

Answer (score 1):

> Logged directly into the database as SYS

Use better a dedicated application user.

Anyway if you use a different user that the schema owner of your objects (FLYWAY_USER) you must qualify **ALL** your references.

especially

```
VALUES
( ( SELECT Nvl( Max(DEPARTMENT_id), 0) + 1  FROM  DEPARTMENT ),
```

should be

```
VALUES
( ( SELECT Nvl( Max(DEPARTMENT_id), 0) + 1  FROM  FLYWAY_USER.DEPARTMENT ),
```